# How do you access params[:model][:field] in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

From what I understand...

- If you have a `form_for @model`, `params[:model]` is available when the form is submitted. Furthermore, if the form has 2 attributes `attr1` and `attr2`, `params[:model][:attr1]` and `params[:model][:attr2]` are available when the form is submitted.
- In Rails 4, you're supposed to write a method `model_params` that says `params.require(:model).permit(:attr1, :attr2)`.
- You'd then use `model_params` like so: `Model.new(model_params)`.

However, what do you do if you only need one of the fields from the form? Like if you only needed `params[:model][:attr1]`?

Example:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    # need access to params[:user][:password] here
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem responsible for this behaviour is [`strong_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). The `permit()` method decides what to pass on to the model based on the attributes you pass to it.

In your case, you passed it `:attr1` and `:attr2`:

```
params.require(:model).permit(:attr1, :attr2)
```

This means the model will have `attr1` and `attr2` set to whatever values were passed from the form.

If you only wanted to set `attr1`, just remove `attr2` from the `permit()` call.

```
params.require(:model).permit(:attr1)
```

You model will not have `attr1` set, but not `attr2`. It's that simple.

You can even permit everything (not recommended) by calling `permit!` with a bang and no arguments.

You can read more about this behaviour on [the gem's Github project page](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

### Update based on the OP's edit

If you need access to `params[:user][:password]` in the controller... well, you just accessed it in your example. You accessed it by typing `params[:user][:password]`.

Nothing prevents you from accessing the params hash directly. strong_parameter's job is to prevent you from mass assigning a hash to a model, that's all.

Comment: So you'd need to write a separate method depending on which attributes you wanted to use?

Comment: @AdamZerner No, you don't. That one method is enough. You can even permit everything by doing a `permit!` with a bang and no arguments.

Comment: So if I needed access to `params[:model]` *and* to `params[:model][:attr1]`, how would I do that?

Comment: @AdamZerner I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify it please?

Comment: Re: update: so you don't need to do anything with `permit` or `require`?

Comment: @AdamZerner That's correct, unless you want to pass the params (a hash) to a model.